Issue with MGIE Project Deployment - KeyError: 'emb'
We successfully reached the final step in the demo.ipynd file, but we encountered a roadblock with a KeyError: 'emb'. Specifically, after training with the dataset and pretrained models you provided, we imported the trained mllm.pt file. However, it seems that the trained model parameters lacks the 'emb' field, which is causing the following line to fail:
EMB = ckpt['emb'].cuda()

The error traceback is as follows:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
     Cell In[3], line 31
     28 image_token_len = (vision_config.image_size//vision_config.patch_size)**2
     30 _ = model.eval()
---> 31 EMB = ckpt['emb'].cuda()
     32 with T.inference_mode(): NULL = model.edit_head(T.zeros(1, 8, 4096).half().to('cuda'), EMB)
     33 print('NULL:', NULL.shape)

KeyError: 'emb'

We aim to address two issues: the environment setup and any errors in the process. We would greatly appreciate any guidance from those who have successfully deployed the MGIE project.

the project can be found in https://github.com/apple/ml-mgie

Just add a breakpoint on L31 to see what happened

Please post a [mre].

@desertnaut I want to showcase an example, but I'm having some difficulties. I think the root cause is that my .pt file did not save the 'emb' key. I'm not sure if it's an issue with the Torch version.
